# Why Does Transaction Manager Overwrite Fragment Tag

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

This is now academic because I have a work-around.
If I construct my own Fragment and return it in `FragmentPagerAdapter's getItem`, everything works fine. But I have no control over the Fragment's tag.

If I use the `TransactionManager`, passing it my Fragment and my own tab, then Android's framework attempts to set its  tab and I get the error message.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment
>   SetupFragment{41f82b08 SetUpTag}: was SetUpTag now
>   android:switcher:2131427454:0

```
/**
 * Return the {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} to be displayed at {@code position}.
 */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    assert (i >= 0 && i < getCount());


    /** Didn't work. A tag is generated internally and wants to replace mine.
     * TabChanged exception.
     */
    String tag=null;
    switch(i) {
        case 0: tag="SetUpTag";break;
        case 1: tag="StartTag";break;
        case 2: tag="FinishTag";break;
        case 3: tag="SummaryTag";break;
        default: break;
    }

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction xact = mFm.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragToReturn =  mFm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if(null == fragToReturn) {
        switch(i) {
            case 0: fragToReturn = new SetupFragment();break;
            case 1: fragToReturn = new StartFragment();break;
            case 2: fragToReturn = new FinishLineFragment();break;
            case 3: fragToReturn = new SummaryFragment();break;
            default: break;
        }
        xact.add(fragToReturn, tag);
    }
    xact.commit();
    return fragToReturn;
}
```

Is it wrong to use the Transaction Manager to prepare a Fragment in this way?

My work around was to simply construct my fragments (with no tag) in getItem.
I needed some way of re-finding my Fragments. Although I can see how tags are constructed internally, I was reluctant to rely on that (it could change). So I grabbed a ref to each Fragment by overriding `instantiateItem`.

Comment: It appears that this code is in a `FragmentPagerAdapter` of some sort. If so, you shouldn't be performing a `FragmentTransaction` - or, consequently, setting a tag - yourself. You just need to return the appropriate `Fragment` from `getItem()`. This would be why you're getting the Exception.

Comment: @Mike M - that's exactly what I did.  It's just that I wanted some control over the tab.  I was curious why it didn't honour mine that was already set.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure exactly how you meant the last part. It's not honoring your tags because the Adapter sets its own tags to track its `Fragment`s. I would say the usual way to handle a limited number of set `Fragment`s like you have is to just keep a List or array of them.

Comment: "control over the tab" should have read "control over **tag**."

Comment: You could always just create your own tag-like implementation, with a `String` field, and the appropriate getter-setter methods. Beyond that, I'm not sure what you'd necessarily need the tag for in this situation, if you're already keeping references otherwise. (But I guess, that was part of the point of the question, probably.)

Comment: The reference worked fine. I think I had seen examples where the tag was used to re-find a Fragment and wanted to use that.  My Main is observing a Data Model and informs the Fragments (Tabs) to keep their state up-to-date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103751/discussion-between-bryant-and-mike-m).